Classic movie with stolen gold melted into golden anchor
Long time ago i watched a film, which was probably a heist movie. There was a group of people that decided to melt  a stolen gold into golden anchor. I don't remember what was the way of gaining this gold (if it was a bank robbery or anything else) but i remember that they painted this anchor black and that due to storm or something like that they lost it. They were trying to transport it (probabaly) to another country. I was trying to find this movie on my own and what i found was that it has a similar style to ,,Robbery'' by Peter Yates.
Thanks in advance.

This sounds really familiar (It's not this one, is it?) Please help us by adding as many details as you can: Approximate year, country\language, color\B&W, particular scenes etc.

Was it the movie L'oro di Londra (Gold in London)? It is Italian (also in English) and directed by Guglielmo Morandi. It seems to be what you are looking for. It was produced in 1967, so I guess that constitutes as "a long time ago". I cannot find very many detail about it but I did find this but I do not know how trustworthy it is, as they mix up the director's name with an alias. The description of the movie is...

With the aid of several accomplices, Ed organizes the assault of a van carrying a load 
      of gold. The mission is carried out perfectly, the gold is melted into a huge anchor and 
      loaded onto a ship just about to leave the harbor. Having tricked the police, they are 
      heading for Gibraltar... when a terrible thunderstorm causes the loss of both the ship and 
      the precious anchor

Hope this is what you were looking for!
